# Get the number of nodes in a variable-length relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I'm searching a books database with `:CATEGORY`s and `:BOOK`s.

I'm trying to find similar books to a current one written by a certain author. `:BOOK`s have `:similar` relationships to other books (the direction of the relationship is not relevant), and I would like to look for up to 3 similar chains. Here's my query:

```
MATCH (currentBook:BOOK {ISBN: {ISBN}})-[:similar*1..3]-(newBook:BOOK {author: {currentAuthor}})
RETURN newBook
```

Here's the problem:

**I need to find out how many similar relationships where used.**

And by that, I mean how much the `*1..3` actually meant for a specific book. So something like this:

```
MATCH (currentBook:BOOK {ISBN: {ISBN}})-[sim:similar*1..3]-(newBook:BOOK {author: {currentAuthor}})
SET newBook.simsUsed = AMOUNT_EXPANDED(sim)
RETURN newBook
```

[Here's a (fake) sample of my dataset.](http://console.neo4j.org/r/89zguj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIZE(sim)` is probably what you are looking for.

For example, this query will return the length of each path:

```
MATCH (currentBook:BOOK {ISBN: "978-0446310789"})-[sim:similar*1..3]-(newBook:BOOK {author: "fake"})
RETURN currentBook, newBook, SIZE(sim) AS lth;
```

You should NOT be setting `newBook.simsUsed` to that value, though, since the path length to any book depends on which book you started from, and the path length (starting from any particular book) might change over time. In general, you should avoid storing redundant data.